# Prevent Linebreak for \cite in \footnote for TufteLatex Class

Tags: footnotes, citing, tufte, sidenotes

I'm using the Tufte-Book class (\documentclass{tufte-book}), which is available [here](https://tufte-latex.github.io/tufte-latex/) and my problem is that if I use the command \cite inside a \footnote{}, i.e.

```
 \sidenote{Some text \cite{test} }
```

the citation is automatically put into a new line. This looks for example like this

*As quoted in*

*Jon Fripp, Deborah Fripp, and
Michael Fripp. Speaking of Science.
Newnes, 1st edition, 4 2000. ISBN
9781878707512*

Is there any way to prevent this linebreak? Concretely I want that the footnote to look like:

*As quoted in Jon Fripp, Deborah Fripp, and
Michael Fripp. Speaking of Science.
Newnes, 1st edition, 4 2000. ISBN
9781878707512*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Tufte-LaTeX. Tufte-LaTeX is printing the full citation appropriately, but it's not printing the in-text citation.

Here's an example document that demonstrates the solution. To use this solution in your own document, copy the code between the `START COPYING HERE` and `END COPYING HERE` lines.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

%
% START COPYING HERE
%
\makeatletter
% Original definition of \cite from natbib package.
\DeclareRobustCommand\natcite{%
  \begingroup\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue\NAT@swatrue
    \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@cites}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@cites}%
}

% Updated definition for Tufte-LaTeX
\renewcommand{\@tufte@infootnote@cite}[1]{%
  \natcite{#1}% <-- added this line
  \@tufte@add@citation{#1}%
}

% Only redefining this to get rid of a spurious space
\renewcommand\@tufte@add@citation[1]{\relax% adds a new bibkey to the list of cite keys
  \ifx\@tufte@citations\@empty\else
    \g@addto@macro\@tufte@citations{,}% separate by commas
  \fi
  \g@addto@macro\@tufte@citations{#1}% <-- stupid whitespace!
}
\makeatother
%
% STOP COPYING HERE
%

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides filler text

\begin{document}

Test.\sidenote{Some of my favorite books are~\cite{Tufte1990,Tufte1997,Tufte2001,Tufte2006}.}
\lipsum[1]

\bibliography{sample-handout}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

[image: Citations in a sidenote]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and citation is still always in a new line. In addition, the sidenote now looks like this: As quoted in Fripp et al. [2000] *LINEBREAK*                    
Jon Fripp, Deborah Fripp, and
Michael Fripp. Speaking of Science.
Newnes, 1st edition, 4 2000. ISBN
9781878707512 . The words Fripp et al. [2000] are new here and the linebreak is unfortunately still there

Comment: The full citation is _supposed_ to be on a new line (a new paragraph, actually). That way you can write, `As noted by~\cite{First2000, Second2001, Third2002}.`

Comment: I've added an example of how this looks with multiple citations.

Comment: @JakobH: Do the updated answer and comments help? (I forgot to mention you in my earlier replies, so it probably didn't notify you.)

Comment: Thanks again for your expanded answer. Unfortunately I'm still trying to avoid that the full citation starts in a new line. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @JakobH: The easiest way would be to write `As quoted in \bibentry{Fripp2000}.`